# Is there any scripture or purana which gives description of hell named Put

Tags: vedas, naraka

It is mentioned in Garuda Purana that if one doesn't begets a couple does not begets a son in their lifetime and the line is broken, they have to spend a certain time in a hell named **Put**. However I am not able to find any descriptions of this hell. In which scripture, does it describe this hell ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer:

There is no hell mentioned in any major canonical text, which goes by the name of 'Put' or 'Puṃ'.
 This hell doesn't exist, as a specific [place](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/26/7/) like Mahāraurava or Kumbhīpāka, etc. The word is more of an 'attributive adjective declaration' of the condition a parent is forced to undergo (especially in their old age) if they lack a progeny. **'Put' is a metaphorical/esoteric signifier of hell-like sufferings.**

How?

### Discussion:

The mention of a hell named - Pum (पुम्) or Put (पुत्) or Pud (पुद्) or Pun (पुन्), occurs in puranas, the Mahabharata ([Chapter CXXIV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01075.htm), Ādi Parva) and Manusmṛti 9.138 too.

We get our answer from Manusmṛti in reference with  Medhātithi’s Manubhāṣya:

> [Manusmṛti 9.138](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201511.html)
>
> पुन्नाम्नो नरकाद् यस्मात् त्रायते पितरं सुतः ।
> तस्मात् पुत्र इति प्रोक्तः स्वयमेव स्वयम्भुवा ॥ १३८ ॥
>
> > 138. Because the Son delivers his father from the hell called ‘Put,’ therefore has he been called ‘Putra,’ ‘Deliverer from Put,’ as ordained by the Self-existent One Himself.

On first reading, this does sound like a specific hell. However, the commentary by Ācārya Medhātithi makes it clear, that it's not so:-

Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):

> अपत्योत्पादनविधिशेषोयमर्थवादः ।
>  पुंनामनरकंचतुर्विधभूतोत्पत्तिः पृथिव्यांव्यपदिश्यते
>  तनस्वायते पुत्रोजातः देवयोनौ जातइत्यर्थः तस्माद्धेतोः पुत्रइति व्यपदिश्यते ॥
>
> > This is a declamatory supplement to the Injunction of begetting
> > children.
> >
> > **‘The hell called Put’—is the name given to the four kinds of elemental
> > life on the Earth.** And from this is the father delivered by his son,
> > as soon as he is born; which means that he is born next in a divine
> > life.
> >
> > It is for this reason that he is called ‘Putra,’ ‘Deliverer from
> > Put.’—(138)
>
> English Translation by Ganganatha Jha

Dr. Surendra Kumar explains this as [follows](https://archive.org/details/manusmritisurendrakumarms_202003_406_t/page/n978/mode/1up):

> (यः) जो (सुतः) पुत्र (पितरम्‌) माता-पिता को (पुम् नाम्नः नरकात्) **"पूम्‌ =वृद्धावस्था आदि से उत्पन्न होने  वाले दुःखों से (त्रायते) रक्षा करता है"** (तस्मात्‌) इस कारण से (स्वयंभुवा स्वयमेव "पुत्रः" इति प्रोक्तः)
> स्वयंभू ईश्वर ने वेदों में बेटे की पूत्र'संज्ञा से अभिहित किया है ॥

So, basically, 'Pum' here signifies the problems/sufferings that arise with old age, which is equated with a horrible experience, similar to hell (narak).

#### Thus, 'Pum' or 'Put' is not a categorical hell, but a signifier of the sufferings brought about by old-age, that a progeny less parent will suffer on the Earth itself since they'll have no-one to care for them.